# Exact $filter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, filter

I have this filter:

```
        $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){                 
        $scope.dataCopy = response.data;                    
        $scope.detMaq = $filter('filter')(angular.copy($scope.dataCopy), {index:hielo, frecuencia:frec, prod_24_h_kg:peso }, false);
        console.log($scope.detMaq);           
        });
```

And I'm building a few div's full of info with data from that data.json.
However, let's say that **peso** is 1.000, so in my filter I want only data that match completely to show up. This however it'll bring up data with 10.000 also, because the filter is not exact.

If I put *true* instead of *false* in the filter, the page will always be blank. even though it should bring information.

Am I missing something? Since it's a triple filter should I put 3 true's?

Here's the json.data

```
[{
"codigo": 21420,
"desc": "......",
"desc_n": "......",
"sistema": "DUCHAS",
"material_carroceria": "A.....",
"refrigerada": "AIRE",
"modelo_cubito_nombre": "ALFA",
"modelo_cubito_nombre_comercial": "",
"modelo_cubito_gr": 17,
"prod_24_h_kg": 22,
"almacen_cubitos_kg": "6",
"almacen_cubitos_cubitos": 400,
"ciclo_cubitos": 18,
"datos_comerciales_ciclo_cubitos": 18,
"compresor_cv": " 1/5",
"remota": null,
"potencia_w_1": 340,
"potencia_w_2": 270,
"voltaje": 220,
"frecuencia": 50,
"fases": "I",
"uk": null,
"gas_tipo": "R404a",
"gas_carga_gr": 180,
"mse_ancho": 350,
"mse_alto": 590,
"mse_fondo": 475,
"mse_alto_con_patas": "SIN PATAS",
"mce_ancho": 430,
"mce_alto": 720,
"mce_fondo": 540,
"peso_neto": 32,
"peso_bruto": 36,
"index": 99,
"enlace_catalogo": "..........",
"familia": ".........."
}, {
"codigo": 21421,
"desc": "...........",
"desc_n": "..........",
"sistema": "DUCHAS",
"material_carroceria": "ACERO INOXIDABLE AISI 304",
"refrigerada": "AGUA",
"modelo_cubito_nombre": "ALFA",
"modelo_cubito_nombre_comercial": "",
"modelo_cubito_gr": 17,
"prod_24_h_kg": 24,
"almacen_cubitos_kg": "6",
"almacen_cubitos_cubitos": 400,
"ciclo_cubitos": 18,
"datos_comerciales_ciclo_cubitos": 18,
"compresor_cv": " 1/5",
"remota": null,
"potencia_w_1": 340,
"potencia_w_2": 210,
"voltaje": 220,
"frecuencia": 50,
"fases": "I",
"uk": null,
"gas_tipo": "R404a",
"gas_carga_gr": 140,
"mse_ancho": 350,
"mse_alto": 590,
"mse_fondo": 475,
"mse_alto_con_patas": "SIN PATAS",
"mce_ancho": 430,
"mce_alto": 720,
"mce_fondo": 540,
"peso_neto": 32,
"peso_bruto": 36,
"index": 99,
"enlace_catalogo": "....",
"familia": "....."
}]
```

Comment: Attach the `data.json` file in the question as well.

Comment: @DineshDevkota I added  a snippet of data.json to the main post.